# Discord.py ask for reply from people with specific role

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command(aliases=['writing'])
async def shiritori(ctx):
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    while True:
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await ctx.send(str(msg))
```

This code wait for user message input and resend the input message to the chat. But the code only replies to the person who started the command using '/writing'. How to make the code to reply to anybody who has discord role '@writer' after anyone starts the command?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `if` statement in your `check()` function and check if message author have `@writer` role:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['writing'])
async def shiritori(ctx):
    def check(msg):
        return msg.channel == ctx.channel and '@writer' in [x.name for x in msg.author.roles]

    while True:
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await ctx.send(str(msg))
```